# Prevent Android Studio to re-format JAVA code

Tags: android, android-studio

is there a way to **totally** isable the re-formatting of the code whenever I close the file or just add a simple }?
Since I cannot set the reformatting as I am used ({ and } in a single line, not after closing bracket in the same line), setting spaces and indenting, I tried to disable it but looks impossible.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

In your **settings- > editor -> code style** you can enable these comments that you can wrap whatever code you don't want to be formatted by AS.
Give it a try :)

To make it work just surround your code with the comments `//@formatter:off` and `//@formatter:on`, like so:

```
//@formatter:off
   public void method() {
     //not formatted
   } 
   //@formatter:on
```

If you want a more "system wide" change you can change the formatting for the Java Language in **Settings> Editor> Code Style-> Language-> Java**

[image]

Here you can change things like tabs and spaces before and after parts of your code.

Comment: I enabled such a option, but how should this prevent to reformat the code? Should I write in every file @formatter:off? (it gives error)

Comment: In Settings> Editor> Code Style-> Language-> Java, click the Wrapping and Braces tab, scroll down to find the option for newline after } and {